# ssh not connecting

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm not able to connect to my computer through ssh.  Here are the steps I've taken already:

1. Linux (Ubuntu) connected to internet--check
2. Ran sudo apt-get install openssh-server (on the receiving machine)
3. Ran sudo apt-get install openssh-client (on both the receiving and remote machines)
4. Ran sudo service ssh status to verify server listening on port 22--check
5. Ran sudo ufw status to check firewall, return status: inactive
6. Got the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses
7. From my remote machine, attempting to log into the server, I use: user@hostipaddress (where "user" is the username on the server, and "hostipaddress" is IPv4 or IPv6 address)

Results: When I use the IPv4 no connection is made and I get a timed out error.  When I use the IPv6 from home (same, local wireless network) I get access and I am prompted for my password (all is good).  However, if I use IPv6 from a remote network, I get a "Network is unreachable" error.

I'm fairly new to Linux and command lines, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: thought: your 'server' isn't connected [directly] to the web, hence it works when tried locally (ipv6 in your description), but you haven't port-forwarded your router so the `ssh` attempts don't get thru to server being ignored (silent rejection) by your router (gateway).

Comment: Tell me more! I just looked up "port forwarding" and I think you may be right. I'm going to try to configure my router to accept inbound requests to my 'server' IP.  Does it matter which IP I use?  Also, what's your recommendation on ports (should I stick with 22, or try a different one, and if so, which?). Thanks for your reply

Comment: if you `ssh`to your external.ip.address; you are attempting to `ssh` to your router itself, not devices on your LAN.  My own router is configured to ignore such requests (unless from internal ip addresses; or known tunnels/vpn). To change my own I `ssh` into my router (*from pre-approved address*), and enter the commands necessary to enable port-forwarding to a set (lan) ip address - but that's off-topic here as it'll be cisco/juniper or whatever brand router you have and nothing at all to do with Ubuntu!

Comment: No. That's ON topic. How do I enable port forwarding to an IP address?

Comment: Ah...I see. I have a Netscape router. Pretty standard. Thank you!